# How to add to end of list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to add one item to the end of a list in prolog, but it keeps on failing.

```
insertAtEnd(X,[ ],[X]).
insertAtEnd(X,[H|T],[H|Z]) :- insertAtEnd(X,T,Z).    

letters([a,b,c]).
```

I do not understand why this below does not work.

```
insertAtEnd(d,letters(Stored),letters(Stored)).
```

I am also attempting to store this list in the variable Stored throughout, but I am not sure if the above is correct way to proceed.

Comment: The need to insert an element at the end of a list strongly suggests that you look into *difference lists*, which will give you O(1) insertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prolog implements a *relational* computation model, and variables can only be instantiated, not assigned. Try

```
?- letters(Stored),
   insertAtEnd(d, Stored, Updated),
   write(Updated).
```

Comment: So the original list is not editable? Lets say I receive another letter e, I would need to call insertAtEnd(e,Updated,UpdatedAgain)? I am trying to use a predicate to update the list without the console.

Comment: Yes, it's a unusual way of performing calculation. It's tightly related to declarative programming. Prolog find applicable rules binding variables, when it need to find alternatives it starts undoing previously established bindings.

Answer (score 5):

you can use [append](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3)
and put your item as second list

like this:

insertAtEnd(X,Y,Z) :- append(Y,[X],Z).

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an
answer really needs a bit more detail than this.  Please
[edit] to explain how this will solve the problem.
Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.